# Symfony forms, show ManyToMany relation as a list of checkboxes instead of a select

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to show a ManyToMany relation in an entity as a list of checkboxes in a form instead of a select with the multiple selection.

In my entity I have this:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Language")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="courses_languages",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $languages = [];
```

And in my FormType for this entity I have this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('languages', ChoiceType::class, [
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ])
    ;
}
```

But when setting multiple and expanded to true I receive this error:

```
Unable to transform value for property path "languages": Expected an array.
```

I've investigated and it is in `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoicesToValuesTransfomer` in function transform

```
public function transform($array)
{
    if (null === $array) {
        return array();
    }

    if (!is_array($array)) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException('Expected an array.');
    }

    return $this->choiceList->getValuesForChoices($array);
}
```

The type of the array is `Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection` so it fails in checking is_array.

How could I fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ChoiceType` by `EntityType` (setting `class` option) or simply leave it `null`, Doctrine is able to guess the type (`EntityType` in this case) from your mapped property:

```
$builder
    ->add('languages', null, [
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true
    ]);
```

In a nutshell, the problem is that `ChoiceType` is designed to work with `array` of elements whilst `EntityType` with `array` and `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` as well.